# Parsing the response from command prompt in jira plugin development

Tags: json, xml, webhooks, jira-plugin

Hello I have written json and xml for Atlassian JIRA cloud plugin development, My plugin is for receiving the events(issue created,updated etc) which occurs in JIRA cloud and i'm successful in that, it is printing the response in cmd(success message:200 ok)
 My question is how to parse that response and how to trigger the mail to all the users in the project

atlassian-connect.json

```
{
"name": "JIRA notification test",
"description": "Atlassian Connect add-on",
"key": "plug-in1",
"baseUrl": "https://2a410c6a.ngrok.io",
"vendor": {
"name": "Stark",
"url": "https://developer.atlassian.com"
},
"authentication": {
"type": "none"
},
"apiVersion": 1,
"modules": {
"webhooks": [
{
"event": "jira:issue_created",
"url": "/issue-created"
},
{
"event": "jira:issue_updated",
"url": "/issue-updated"
}
]
},
"scopes": [
"read"
]
}

atlassian-plugin.xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<atlassian-plugin key="plug-in1" name="PlugIn" plugins-version="2">
<plugin-info>
<description>Atlassian Connect add-on</description>
<version>1</version>
<vendor name="My Organization, Inc" url="https://developer.atlassian.com" />
</plugin-info>
<remote-plugin-container key="container" display-url="http://localhost:8000">
</remote-plugin-container>
</atlassian-plugin>
```